# Dynamic LINQ query, select max column name based on variable

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Why doesn't that following code produce the expected result?

```
public string LinqTest()
        {
            //hardcoded here for clarity's sake
            //real code will hit a database
            var jsonString = "DrugClass";
            List<Drugs> drugList = new List<Drugs>()
            {
                new Drugs() { DrugId=1, DrugClass="HHH", DrugDosage=120, DrugName="Drug1"},
                new Drugs() { DrugId=2, DrugClass="H2H", DrugDosage=100, DrugName="Drug2"},
                new Drugs() { DrugId=3, DrugClass="HHH", DrugDosage=100, DrugName="Drug3"},
                new Drugs() { DrugId=4, DrugClass="WA2", DrugDosage=200, DrugName="Drug4"}
            };
            var query = (from d in drugList
                        select d.GetType().GetProperty(jsonString)).Max();
            return query.ToString();
        }
```

I would expect this code to select the property DrugClass from the collection you see above and return "WA2". Why isn't this the case?

Comment: So what did it actually return?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take off the `.Max()` from this chunk of code, you'll see that it's returning an `IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>`... not what you were wanting.

```
var query = (from d in drugList
             select d.GetType().GetProperty(jsonString)).Max();
```

You were almost there... once you get the `PropertyInfo` class, you can use its `GetValue` method to get the value of that property from an actual instance of that class.

In the code below, I've separated out the code that gets the property (the `let property = ...` statement) from the code that gets the value (the last line) from the particular `Drugs` class being evaluated. This should do the trick for you (worked for me in LINQPad).

```
var query = (from d in drugList
             let property = d.GetType().GetProperty(jsonString)
             select property.GetValue(d, null)).Max();
```

Note: If you're using .NET 4.5 or above, you can drop the `null` from `GetValue` and just do `property.GetValue(d)`... it's required in earlier versions of .NET since there's no overload that just takes `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: What's the second parameter null for?  And thanks by the way, if I didn't leave work to make french toast then I would have responded sooner.

Comment: It's an optional index for indexed properties that you have to set to null for non-indexed properties. If you're in .NET 4.5, you don't need that anymore. See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.100).aspx). Edited the question to clarify as well.

Comment: Also... french toast: I'm jealous ;)

Comment: With a pomegranate lime marmalade, that's the part to be jealous about.

Answer (score 0):

`d.GetType().GetProperty()` isn't returning what you think it is. It's returning a [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object that describes the property in relation to the Type, not to the particular instance, which is what is appears you want.

What you need to do after you have that description object, is evaluate the property on a particular instance using the [`GetValue(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

I believe, if you change the LINQ to be something like (untested)

```
var query = (from d in drugList
    select d.GetType().GetProperty(jsonString).GetValue(d).ToString()).Max();
```

You'll get closer to what you're looking for.